# Matplotlib crash in gui

Tags: python, matplotlib, crash, tkinter, imshow

I would like to draw a matrix with imshow with tkinter in a gui. The problem is that after further updates, the gui crash. I don't manage to find answer on the web. You could help me please?

The code:

```
from numpy import *
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = Tk()
f1 = Figure()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="x")
a = f1.add_subplot(111)
a.get_axes().set_frame_on(True)
ini = [[i] * 100 for i in range(100)]
cax = a.matshow(ini)

while True:
    mat = random.randint(0, 2**16-1, (1000, 1000))
    cax.set_data(mat)
    canvas.draw()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Thank you for your suggestion fhdrsdg but doing this way freeze the windows during the exection of redraw which is boring especially when this previous has a lot of stuff to do.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import Button, Label, Text, Checkbutton, Radiobutton, Frame, Tk, Entry, INSERT, StringVar, IntVar, Toplevel, END
from ttk import Notebook, Combobox
from numpy import arange, zeros, array, uint16, empty, divide, random, ravel
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.image import AxesImage
import time
from threading import Thread
import os



class Image_direct(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.encore = True

    def run(self):
        """This loop can be long ~10s"""
        while self.encore:
            time.sleep(1)
            app.cax.set_extent((0, 1023, 1023, 0))
            mat = random.randint(0, 2**16-1, (1024, 1024)).astype("uint16")
            app.update_camera(mat)

    def stop(self):
        self.encore = False


class Deu(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.creer_applets()

    def creer_applets(self):
        self.fen4 = Frame(fen)
        self.fen4.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")
        self.fen1 = Frame(fen, width=200)
        self.fen1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)
        self.note = Notebook(fen, width=1)
        self.tab_mat = Frame(self.note)
        self.note.add(self.tab_mat, text = "Caméra", compound="top")
        self.note.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.fen3 = Frame(fen, width=250)
        self.fen3.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)

        Button(self.fen4, text="Quit", command=self.aurevoir).pack(fill="x", side="top")

        self.interp = StringVar()
        self.interp.set("none")
        liste_interp = ["none", "nearest", "bilinear", "bicubic", "spline16", "spline36", "hanning", "hamming", "hermite", "kaiser", "quadric", "catrom", "gaussian", "bessel", "mitchell", "sinc", "lanczos"]
        self.choix_interp = Combobox(self.tab_mat, textvariable=self.interp, state="readonly", width=10)
        self.choix_interp['values'] = liste_interp
        self.cmap = StringVar()
        self.cmap.set("jet")
        palettes = sorted(m for m in cm.datad if not m.endswith("_r"))
        self.choix_palette = Combobox(self.tab_mat, textvariable=self.cmap, state="readonly", width=10)
        self.choix_palette['values'] = palettes
        self.bouton_palette = Button(self.tab_mat, text="Changer la palette", command=self.changer_cmap)

        self.f1 = Figure()
        self.canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f1, master=self.tab_mat)
        self.canvas1.show()
        self.canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas1, self.tab_mat)
        self.a = self.f1.add_subplot(111)
        self.bg = self.canvas1.copy_from_bbox(self.a.bbox)
        self.a.get_axes().set_frame_on(True)
        ini = random.randint(0, 2**16-1, (1024, 1024))
        self.cax = self.a.matshow(ini, cmap=self.cmap.get(), interpolation=self.interp.get(), picker=True, alpha=1.0)
        self.a.format_coord = lambda x, y: 'x=%d, y=%d, z=%d' % (x, y, ini[round(y), round(x)])
        self.cbar = self.f1.colorbar(self.cax)
        self.cbar.set_label("coups")
        self.bouton_palette.pack(side="left")
        self.choix_interp.pack(side="left")
        self.choix_palette.pack(side="left")

        Button(self.tab_mat, text=">", command=lambda: self.changer_cbar(1)).pack(side="right")
        self.cbar_auto = IntVar()
        self.chb3 = Checkbutton(self.tab_mat, text="Auto?", variable=self.cbar_auto, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, indicatoron=0, command=lambda: self.changer_cbar(0))
        self.chb3.select()
        self.chb3.pack(side="right")
        Button(self.tab_mat, text="<", command=lambda: self.changer_cbar(-1)).pack(side="right")

        self.bouton_direct_on = Button(self.fen3, width=20, text="Démarrer le direct", command=self.image_direct_on)
        self.bouton_direct_on.place(x=0, y=400)
        self.bouton_direct_off = Button(self.fen3, width=20, text="Arrêter le direct", command=self.image_direct_off)
        self.bouton_direct_off.config(state="disabled")
        self.bouton_direct_off.place(x=0, y=430)

    def changer_cbar(self, sens):
        if sens == -1:
            self.cbar.set_clim(vmin=self.cax.get_array().min(), vmax=0.9*self.cbar.get_clim()[1])
        elif sens == 0 and self.cbar_auto.get():
            self.cbar.set_clim(vmin=self.cax.get_array().min(), vmax=self.cax.get_array().max())
        elif sens == 1:
            self.cbar.set_clim(vmin=self.cax.get_array().min(), vmax=2*self.cbar.get_clim()[1])
        self.cax.set_clim(self.cbar.get_clim())
        self.canvas1.restore_region(self.bg)
        self.a.draw_artist(self.f1)
        self.canvas1.blit(self.f1.bbox)

    def changer_cmap(self):
        self.cax.set_cmap(self.cmap.get())
        self.cax.set_interpolation(self.interp.get())
        self.canvas1.draw()

    def update_camera(self, mat):
        xmin = min([int(i) for i in app.a.get_xlim()])
        xmax = max([int(i) for i in app.a.get_xlim()])
        ymin = min([int(i) for i in app.a.get_ylim()])
        ymax = max([int(i) for i in app.a.get_ylim()])
        self.a.format_coord = lambda x, y: 'x=%d, y=%d, z=%d' % (x, y, mat[round(y), round(x)])
        self.cax.set_data(mat)
        self.changer_cbar(0)

    def image_direct_on(self):
        self.bouton_direct_off.config(state="normal")
        self.bouton_direct_on.config(state="disabled")
        self.dire = Image_direct()
        self.dire.setDaemon(True)
        self.dire.start()

    def image_direct_off(self):
        self.bouton_direct_off.config(state="disabled")
        self.bouton_direct_on.config(state="normal")
        self.dire.stop()
        del self.dire

    def aurevoir(self):
        try:
            self.dire.isAlive()
        except:
            pass
        else:
            self.dire.stop()
        fen.quit()
        fen.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fen = Tk()
    fen.geometry("1300x750")
    app = Deu(fen)
    fen.mainloop()
```

What is strange is that:

- the crash occurs when the cursor is on the image
- under linux, there is no crash.

It can happen in few seconds or few minutes when the cursor is over the image or when I zoom/dezoom the image. Then the window becomes white, and a pop-up appears with the message "pythonw.exe not responding". Idle says nothing. I am in the complete fog :/

Comment: what error do you get

Comment: What complicate the problem is that there is no error message. It seems to be a memory leak or a cache memory overflow...

Comment: I use python 2.7.8, matplotlib 1.3.1. executed with win7 64bits with the Unofficial Windows 64 bits Binaries for Python Extension Packages: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with running the `while True` loop.
Try to limit the time between each repetition using the `after` method.
The following code updates the canvas every 100ms

```
from numpy import *
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = Tk()
f1 = Figure()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="x")
a = f1.add_subplot(111)
a.get_axes().set_frame_on(True)
ini = [[i] * 100 for i in range(100)]
cax = a.matshow(ini)

def redraw():
    mat = random.randint(0, 2**16-1, (1000, 1000))
    cax.set_data(mat)
    canvas.draw()
    root.after(100, redraw)

redraw()
root.mainloop()
```